# Reliably remove baseline skip between text and math

Tags: amsmath

I'm using ntheorem, with a proof environment that roughly works like

```
\newenvironment{proof}{\par\textbf{Proof} }{}
```

My proofs are just blocks of `align`, so I want to get rid of the long space between “Proof” and the first line of the equation. This could be done like

```
\begin{flalign}
&\text{\textbf{Proof} to show: }&  x &= y &\\
&& more & math
\end{flalign}
```

But the “Proof” text comes from the environment, I can't move it into the flalign. So I tried to just set the first math baseline to the last text baseline which would allow writing:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7cm}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\antiskip}
\setlength{\antiskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\addtolength{\antiskip}{\baselineskip}

% Ok
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
\begin{align}\noalign{\vskip-\antiskip}
    \qquad\text{baseline } x^2
\end{align}

% Breaks
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
\begin{align}\noalign{\vskip-\antiskip}
    \qquad\text{baseline } \sum_{i=0}^n
\end{align}

% Desired outcome (yes, really)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
\begin{align}\noalign{\vskip-\antiskip\vskip-1.5ex}
    \qquad\text{baseline } \sum_{i=0}^n
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

TL;DR: I want it to look like (3)

Comment: With `standard` option loaded in `ntheorem` package, there is a predefined `proof` theorem environment.

Comment: That's what I'm using. It has the same problem though, the "Proof" text is defined in the environment. If it wasn't the easy solution would be using the second block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this?

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\renewtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{proof}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac.

With \texttt{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
a_{11}& =b_{11}&
a_{12}& =b_{12}\\
a_{21}& =b_{21}&
a_{22}& =b_{22}+c_{22}
\end{flalign}

With \texttt{equation}
\begin{equation}%\noalign{\vskip-\antiskip}
    %\qquad\text{baseline } 
    \sum_{i=1}^n (x+y)^n = x^n+\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}y+\binom{n}{2}x^{n-2}y^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}xy^{n-1}+y^n
\end{equation}

With \texttt{align}
\begin{align}
f(c_1)\cdot\Delta x&=c_1\cdot\Delta x=0\cdot\frac{8}{n}\\
f(c_2)\cdot\Delta x&=c_2\cdot\Delta x=\frac{8}{n}\cdot\frac{8}{n}\\
f(c_3)\cdot\Delta x&=c_3\cdot\Delta x=2\cdot\frac{8}{n}\cdot\frac{8}{n}\\
f(c_4)\cdot\Delta x&=c_4\cdot\Delta x=3\cdot\frac{8}{n}\cdot\frac{8}{n}\\
\vdots\\
f(c_k)\cdot\Delta x&=c_k\cdot\Delta x=(k-1)\cdot\frac{8}{n}\cdot\frac{8}{n}=(k-1)\cdot\frac{64}{n^2}\\
\vdots\\
f(c_n)\cdot\Delta x&=c_n\cdot\Delta x=(n-1)\cdot\frac{8}{n}\cdot\frac{8}{n}=(n-1)\cdot\frac{64}{n^2}
\end{align}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I have to go now. Please leave your comment if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}` and my previous solution `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}` have the same problem with higher-than-normal math lines as the `\vskip` one in my question, additionally they break `\intertext{}` because that uses `\abovedisplayskip` too.

Comment: @pascal I am sorry but I don't understand what you really want to do. Do you want to make your inline math behave like display math without messing up with the other lines? Inline math are displayed the way they are precisely because you don't want the problem you are encountering to happen. I don't know if I could be of much help here now. `:)`

Comment: no I want exactly what I produced as (3) in my question, mad as it sounds. (In my actual use case there's no text clashing into the formula, it's just there to show the line heights)